# more than one rootQuery object in GraphQL

Tags: refactoring, graphql, graphql-js

Is there a way I can refactor the rootQuery object by creating more than one rootQuery objects and combine them together in the schema?

so for now we have like one rootQuery full of multiple roots and then we make a schema saying we have this one root Query. What we write is

```
var schema = new GraphQLSchema({
 query: RootQuery
})
```

What I want would be like

```
var schema = new GraphQLSchema({
 query: [RootQuery1, RootQuery2]
})
```

is there a way I can do this in GraphQL? it will help refactor.

Answer (score 5):

**No** it can't, `GraphQLSchema` `queryType` only accepts a `GraphQLObjectType` which is `RootQuery`, it can't be of ArrayType with multiple `GraphQLObjectType`

All of the your Types should be declared in the main `queryType` which is `RootQuery`

Below is the Source code of GraphQLSchema

https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/blob/master/src/type/schema.js#L58

```
export class GraphQLSchema {
  _queryType: GraphQLObjectType; // accepts GraphQLObjectType not array
  _mutationType: ?GraphQLObjectType;
  _subscriptionType: ?GraphQLObjectType;
  _directives: Array<GraphQLDirective>;
  _typeMap: TypeMap;
  _implementations: { [interfaceName: string]: Array<GraphQLObjectType> };
  _possibleTypeMap: ?{
    [abstractName: string]: { [possibleName: string]: boolean }
  };
```